# AngularJS: ngModel with ngSwitch, cannot watch?

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to make a very simple signup form, which is supposed to work in 2 steps.

- I ask the user for his email in the first step
- in the second step, I ask the user for the other details (step == 2).

The template is simple;

```
<div class="input-group layout-container" ng-switch on="step">
    <!-- Login -->
    <img src="images/yeoman.png">
    <p>{{msg}}</p>
    <form name="signup">
        <input type="text" class="form-control login" placeholder="firstname" ng-model="firstname" ng-switch-when="2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control login" placeholder="lastname"ng-model="lastname" ng-switch-when="2">
        <input type="email" class="form-control login" placeholder="email" ng-model="email" ng-switch-when="1" required>
        <span class="error" ng-show="signup.input.$error.required">Cannot be blank</span>
        <span class="error" ng-show="signup.input.$error.email">Not a valid email</span>
        <input type="password" class="form-control login" placeholder="password" ng-model="pass" ng-switch-when="2"> <br/><br/>
        <div class="btn-container">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="next()">Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, there's some basic validation going on as well, and I assign the value of the email to a model I call email.

And the controller goes like this:

```
.controller('SignupCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "First, your email";
    $scope.step = 1;
    $scope.email = ''; // this still doesn't help
    $scope.$watch('email', function (now, then, scope) {
        console.log('email change', now, then);
    });
    $scope.next = function () {
        $scope.step = Math.min($scope.step + 1, 2);
    };
})
```

The problem is this: the $watch on 'email' doesn't ever trigger at all. Where's this going wrong?

Comment: and where do you define `email` in the scope? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new

Comment: @Mosho added `$scope.email = ''` to the controller; still nothing. (added the edit above to the code also)

Comment: @Ashesh `ngSwitch` creates a new scope. `email` as referenced by your watch will not point to the variable you'd expect.

Comment: @miqid ah, thanks, that helps clarify things. That's quite weird imho. Any way I can access that scope in my controller? That does affect how modular/concise I'd have liked this controller to be, though.

Comment: @Ashesh a rather crude way is to prefix your input model variables with `$parent` such that it will bind to the controller (i.e. `ng-model="$parent.email"`). There are other alternatives, such as assignment by object references as opposed to primitives, as you are doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working jsfiddle (of just the part you have a problem with): [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9y38G/4)

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['one','two'];
    $scope.selection = 'two';
    $scope.data = {email:''};
    $scope.$watch('data.email', function (now, then, scope) {
        console.log('email change', now, then);
    });
}
```

Note that it will only trigger the watch if the email is valid if the input is `type="email"`.

**Edit**: updated for use with ng-switch.

Explanation: As noted by miqid, when you use primitives, child scopes have no access to parent scope variables, but when they're objects angular creates a reference in the child scopes.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't what I'm going for. I know that will work. As @miqid pointed out, I need it to work with `ngSwitch`, which, strangely so, creates another scope. I don't really get why that was deemed necessary as switch is usually part of controller logic.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. Working on it.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the time you've put into this. But again, the behaviour is strange. I'd want the watch to trigger on every change in `email` – right now, it triggers only on the first change and `now` and `then` are `undefined`.

What I was going for was to keep an eye on the email changes and keep validating it with my backend (to see if the email was available, etc.)

Comment: Are you talking about my fiddle? it works for me. The link is updated.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. It does work, thanks! Didn't keep in mind that `$watch` would fire only after validation. Accepted +1. Thanks again.

Comment: It actually fires when you set it to the initial value as well, but since it's an empty string you saw nothing but if you change it, it will show when the fiddle is loaded. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @miqid, that `ng-switch` creates a new scope implicitly. All the value changes of `<input>` are actually happened in this isolated child scope. Its parent, where you are doing `$watch`, will NOT be notified. That's the reason why you cannot watch the variable changes. This is a common pitfall to angular users.

**LT;DR** simply change any `ng-model="foo"` to `ng-model="$parent.foo"` in your `ng-switch` block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After my experience with AngularJS I've given up frontend development for good and moved to my beloved backend stuff.